# Flutter - Detect if Widget 1 is visible after Navigator.pop() on Widget 2?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

so the scenario is this:
Widget1 is visible and on a user click calls `Navigator.push(..Widget2)`
Now, the user clicked back on Widget2 so `Navigator.pop()` is called
and now Widget1 is visible again. Is there a way to detect that Widget1 is visible again?
Something like `onResume()` on Android.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a widget called "Focus" which allows to add events when focus is gained or lost. With this, you could use `onFocusChange` to handle your desired event.

More information: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Focus-class.html